# Next.js pass dynamically loaded server-side data available to all components

Tags: javascript, next.js, middleware, react-context

(I'm new to Next.js, and I took over a project that was written with it, so excuse if this is something obvious that I'm not seeing)

I have some data that I need to load server-side each request. It was written in `getServerSideProps` and was working just fine for one page. However now I need to have many pages, with many reused components between them down the component tree. I need a mechanism to have a globally available variable that I can access from each component, and that variable needs to be populated at server side. Repeating same code over and over in `getServerSideProps` and passing all the data downstream via props is too cumbersome and redundant, I need a centralized/static/hook(y) approach.

I'm doing the API call at `middleware.js` at request time and get the required data. How do I provide that data to all components down the tree? If it was purely client side, I'd have used a Context/store, yet I couldn't figure out how to pass data at server to client components.

Comment: Maybe you should look into ["Context API"](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or Redux?

Comment: @VladimirJovanović as I've already stated clearly in the question:

If it was purely client side, I'd have used a Context/store, yet I couldn't figure out how to pass data at server to client components.

Comment: [The data you return from the `getServerSideProps` function](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) is available to a page component via prop(s). You can then streamline the data to other components via the "Context API" or Redux.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović as I've already stated clearly in the question: Repeating same code over and over in getServerSideProps and passing all the data downstream via props is too cumbersome and redundant.

Comment: You can create a re-usable function that you'd call on each `getServerSideProps`, you don't necessarily have to duplicate code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve data server side and save in context with Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66106408/retrieve-data-server-side-and-save-in-context-with-next-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up using `App.getInitialProps` to fetch the needed data, pass it to my custom `App` component there as a prop. The rest is trivial in React side: wrapping the app in a context provider that I created with the value read from app props, and used a hook that I wrote to access the data wherever I need.