# How should we use React's Context API in Next.js 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

We were using react's context API in our next.js 12 apps.

We want to upgrade to next.js 13.

We get this error:

> react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext is not a function

For this code:

```
import React from 'react'

const SiteContext = React.createContext()

export default SiteContext
```

What should we do now? I can't find resources online for this.

Also, we need the Context API on the server because SEO matters and we don't want to render on the client.

Comment: try, change export default to export

Comment: @JacksonQuintero, that won't even compile. There is either deafult exports, or named exports in JS.

Comment: You can change it to a client component, as for the SEO, add a different head.js file for each page inside the app folder. It should work just as the old Head component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve data server side and save in context with Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66106408/retrieve-data-server-side-and-save-in-context-with-next-js)

Comment: I've written a detailed answer about how to use Context alongside RSC, and also create a kind of server context using "cache" https://stackoverflow.com/a/75533592/5513532

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that you need the "use client" directive.

The error is being suppressed because of your import statement.  Change the import to `import { useContext } from 'react'` and you will get the following error:

> You're importing a component that needs createContext. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.

Checkout the [beta docs for more details](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components), but basically, ALL components inside the app directory are server components.  For client components, you need to use the directive.

```
"use client"

import React from 'react'

const SiteContext = React.createContext()

export default SiteContext
```

Comment: Does this mean that we can't use Context API on the server side? Is it a React limitation, or a Next limitation?

Comment: Yup, useState, useEffect and createContext are client-only features.  The "use client" directive was introduced with React as part of the Server Components features, so it is a "React thing" but I'm not sure it's a limitation per se.  If your component needs to support user interactions such as those that would require state, then it's a client component by definition.

Comment: yes it's a client component. But can we render it on the server for the sake of SEO? Let's say we want to have a contact us form. It's a client component. But the `/contact` page needs to be rendered on the server so that Google can index it.

Comment: Short answer is yes.  Check out [docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/fundamentals#client-and-server-rendering-at-the-component-level) for the details, but yes, both Server and Client Components can be prerendered on the server at build time.

Answer (score 4):

In app directory you create your context inside a client component. Because you will need `useState,useEffect` hooks. the way you crete context api is same as before. But you need to wrap top layout file with this context.

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head />
      <body>
        <main>
          <AuthContext>
            <main>
              {children}
            </main>
          </AuthContext>
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

`AuthContext` is a client component and wraps `children`. Normally client components cannot render server components but since we are using `children` prop, components inside `children` tree can be server components.

the problem with context api on the app directory is any component that needs to reach context has to be a client component because it needs to use `useContext` hook.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that placing any component inside of `AuthContext` does not automatically make it a client-side component? 

So if I place a component that does not useContext with `AuthContext`, it will still be rendered as a server component?

Comment: @LeeHarrison  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74992326/does-use-client-in-next-js-13-root-layout-make-whole-routes-client-component/75480826#75480826

Comment: Yes this is called "interleaving" https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#interleaving-server-and-client-components

Answer (score 2):

Next 13 does not support the React Context API on the server is the issue. Considering SEO matters you would have to stick with the old apps/pages approach for now. I hope they support context soon.