# Does 'use client' in Next.js 13 root layout make whole routes client component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I was trying Nextjs 13 with Next-auth and Apollo Client. For that we wrap the root layout with the providers but we also need `'use client'` to be specified. I have no problem with the libraries.

**But what is confusing to me is that nextjs 13 app dir uses a server-first approach by default, and if I treat the root layout as a client, does it make all the pages client? Because, afak, the root layout is the parent of whole routes**

[Github discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/44648)

Comment: regarding to document you can have client component as parent and server components as children, check this out :
https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/fundamentals#component-level-client-and-server-rendering

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[from here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts) (thanks to Paul Serre for commenting)

> The root layout is a Server Component by default and can not be set to
> a Client Component.

in app directory, server components can render client components but client components cannot render server components. [Because](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns)

> Since Client Components are rendered after Server Components, you
> cannot import a Server Component into a Client Component module (since
> it would require a new request back to the server). Instead, you can
> pass a Server Component as props to a Client Component.

the only exception is if the client component renders component which is passed as children. this is a Layout. From the same docs:

> Layouts are Server Components by default but can be set to a Client
> Component.

```
"use client";

export default function Layout({children}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">        
      <head />
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Since the root layout component is rendering `children`, any component inside `children` tree can be server component

this would not be accepted

```
"use client";

export default function Layout({children}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">        
      <head />
      <body> 
         // if you manually pass server component inside client component
         <AnyServerRenderedComponent/>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more clear with your example? I can't see any client component here. Weren't you saying that the client component should render the children passed to it as server components? I don't see a `use client` directive anywhere

Comment: @sayandcode i did not say this `the client component should render the children passed to it as server components`

Comment: @sayandcode I said, if you pass `children` prop to a client component, any component inside `children tree` can be a server component

Comment: Oh, so as per your edited answer, `{children}` should work as a server component, but explicit `<MyServerComponent/>` wont work as a server component, within a layout that has a `use client` directive?

Comment: @sayandcode correct. It is true for all client components, not just for layout

Comment: Reference for this matter: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#recommended-pattern-passing-server-components-to-client-components-as-props

Comment: The doc literally says : `The root layout is a Server Component by default and can not be set to a Client Component.` 
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts so I'm really confused about this answer being the accepted one

Comment: @PaulSerre you are right. I was just learning nextjs13 at that time did not pay attention that much. I updated the answer referencing your comment. It makes sense though, if `RootLayout` was client your app would be a client side app :)

Comment: @Yilmaz No worries, I'm currently struggling migrate to app folder so I don't know much yet either.
In this link https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials, they tell that if you want to put it at `RootLayout, you have to create a Client component with use-client directive, and put it into the RootLayout.

Comment: @PaulSerre you can use `use client` anywhere except `RootLayout`. if you could make `RootLayout` client then app directory would be pointless

Comment: Yes I know, it's not what I'm telling to do. I say that you have to create a Providers component with use-client directive and children props, put all your contexts here, and then use it in RootLayout

Comment: @PaulSerre I already mentioned this "server components can render client components". `RootLayoout` server and can render cleint components

Answer (score 15):

[EDIT]

Even with the solution below, I couldn't make it work because of CSS-in-JS libraries, MUI and emotion in my case. You can check if yours is supported on this link:

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-in-js

For me, Vercel rushed with its use of server components. They released NextJS 13 claiming it was stable, but if it's incompatible with a large portion of UI frameworks, it's completely useless. Especially if it's a front-end framework... This habit that engineers have of always wanting to use the latest technologies is exhausting.

---

As the doc said, here: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials you can't put 'use client' directive on the RootLayout, but you can create a Client component with children props and use it in your RootLayout

```
'use client'
 
import { ThemeProvider } from 'acme-theme'
import { AuthProvider } from 'acme-auth'
 
export function Providers({ children }) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <AuthProvider>{children}</AuthProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

And then:

```
import { Providers } from './providers'

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Comment: This answer is helpful for this particular case. Thank you.

Comment: This is the way to go if you want to use Next's App Router but want to do routing on the client