# Nextjs 13.4 Next-Auth 4.2 signIn("credentials", { }); not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am using next-auth credentials in my next project, but It seems that the `signIn()` from `next-auth/react` is not working correctly. I still get redirected to admin page no matter if the login info is correct or not.

```
{error: null, status: 200, ok: true, url: 'https://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?csrf=true'}
```

Here is some information

app/components/forms/SignInForm.tsx

```
'use client';


import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { redirect } from 'next/dist/server/api-utils';
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react'; // Fixed import




const SignInForm = () => {

  const router  = useRouter();

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) => {

    try {
      // I have verified that values.email and values.password are correct!
      // I think that signIn is where the problem is!
      const signInData = await signIn("credentials", {
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password,
        redirect: false,
      });

      if(signInData?.error) {
        console.log(signInData.error)
      } else{
        router.push("/admin");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error signing in:", error);
    }
  }
   

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className='w-full'>
        <div className='space-y-2'>
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name='email'
            render={({ field }) => (
             
                  <Input placeholder='mail@example.com' {...field} />
                
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name='password'
            render={({ field }) => (
             
                  <Input
                    type='password'
                    placeholder='Enter your password'
                    {...field}
                  />
                
            )}
          />
        </div>
        <Button className='w-full mt-6' type='submit'>
          Sign in
        </Button>
      </form>
      
      
    </Form>
  );
};

export default SignInForm;
```

app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "@/lib/auth";

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

app/lib/auth.ts

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter"
import { db } from "./db";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt'
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/sign-in'
  },

  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
    
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        // removing logic to see why I am still being redirected
        return null
      }
    })
  ]

}
```

I am unsure why I am still being redirected to `/admin` even though I clearly put `return null` on the auth.ts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you `console.log(signInData)` see if it has `error` property. in next-auth 4 it has but in case there is a bug

Comment: It does @Yilmaz. But the error is null

Comment: so you are saying, even though you are returning `null` in `authorize`, `signinData.error` is `null`

Comment: Yeah. I am being redirected no matter the email/password. I simply returned null in the authorize to see if that would stop me being redirected, but it did not work.

Comment: what if instead of returning null, `throw Error("")`

Comment: Yeah, there is most likely a problem with `signInData` reaching `authorize`.
I replaced `return null` with `throw Error("")` in `authorize` but `signInData` still has `{error: null, status: 200, ok: true, url: 'https://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?csrf=true'}` and redirects me.

Comment: Can u create a mininal repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see `SessionProvider` is wrapping your app. that is why `signIn` function is not communicating with `authorize`

in the `RootLayout`

```
"use client";


import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <SessionProvider>
          <main className="h-screen flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
            <Navbar />
            {children}
          </main>
        </SessionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: I can only use `SessionProvider ` in client side

Comment: yeah, i had to add `"use client"`

Comment: since  rootLayout is a  cliemt component, does not mean that your entire app is client. you can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74992326/does-use-client-in-next-js-13-root-layout-make-whole-routes-client-component/75480826#75480826

Comment: Will this have any issue with sessions? I created `app/(dashboard)/admin/page.tsx` and added `const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)` (with proper imports). The value is null, even though I have `next-auth.session-token`

Comment: you have to implement `session` callback after `authorize`.

Comment: I was able to get the sign in to work, but now I am struggling with getting data from the session. Do you mind taking a look at a updated repo to see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: i dont see any repo link. if you have an issue, you should be asking a separate question.

Comment: you did not implement session callback. add this `callbacks: {
  async session({ session, user }: any) {
    if (session && user) {
      session.user.id = user.id;
    }
    return session;
  },
},` to `lib/auth`,  after providers

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the signIn call correctly interprets the `redirect: false` and the logic within your signIn function's if-else block. If signInData?.error is not truthy (because authorize returns null, which might not set an error as expected), the code proceeds to redirect to /admin.

Check for Undefined:  Modify your if-else block:

```
if (signInData?.error) {
    console.log(signInData.error) // Log the error for analysis
} else if (signInData) { // Check if signInData itself is truthy
    router.push("/admin");
} else {
    // Handle sign-in failure case - display an error message
}
```

Handle Sign-In Failure: Introduce a way to notify the user of an unsuccessful sign-in:

```
 } else {
     // Handle sign-in failure case 
     setError('Invalid credentials'); // Example - assuming you have a way to manage an 'error' state.
 }
```

I had a very similar issue with a Next 13 IT Helpdesk project I was working on a couple months ago, so hopefully this helps you out.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think it's a problem with my if-statements. signInData is `{error: null, status: 200, ok: true, url: 'https://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?csrf=true'}` before I check anything.