# Pass props to page.jsx child from root layout (next.js 13)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

How do you pass props to the the page.jsx of layout? (NEXT 13)

```
//app/blog/layout.jsx

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Sidebar />
      {/*How do I pass any props from this root layout to this {children} that Im getting from page.jsx*/}
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Basically, How do you pass a prop to a function prop (Next. JS 13)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve data server side and save in context with Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66106408/retrieve-data-server-side-and-save-in-context-with-next-js)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [next13 docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts) you cannot:

> It's not possible to pass data between a parent layout and its
> children. However, you can fetch the same data in a route more than
> once, and React will automatically dedupe the requests without
> affecting performance.

Because the layout component refers to a component that defines the overall structure and arrangement of other components within an application or a specific section of the UI. it is not designed to implement state management. its whole purpose is to reduce the time to first render to increase the user experience

But I found a way. In `Rootlayout`, `console.log(props)`

```
export default function RootLayout(props) {
  console.log("props in layout",props)
  return (
        <div>
          {props.children}
        </div>
  );}
```

this is what you will see

```
props in layout {
  children: {
    '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
    type: {
      '$$typeof': Symbol(react.module.reference),
      filepath: '/home/tesla//node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js',
      name: '',
      async: false
    },
    key: null,
    ref: null,
    props: {
      parallelRouterKey: 'children',
      segmentPath: [Array],
      error: undefined,
      errorStyles: undefined,
      loading: undefined,
      loadingStyles: undefined,
      hasLoading: false,
      template: [Object],
      templateStyles: undefined,
      notFound: [Object],
      notFoundStyles: undefined,
      childProp: [Object],
      rootLayoutIncluded: true
    },
    _owner: null,
    _store: {}
  },
  // THIS IS HOW WE PASS PROPS
  params: {}
}
```

Many properties are not extensible but `params`. we can dynamically add properties to this object. for example

```
     props.params.newProp = "testing";
```

Now visit `page.js` and

```
const Page = (props) => {
  console.log("props in page", props);
  return ()}
```

you will see that props is added to the `params` object

[image]

No matter what I tried, `page.tsx` had only two props: `params` and `searchParams`. `searchParams` is automatically populated if you have query parameters on url. So, I think `params` are the only way to pass props from the root layout. you can pass functions too

Comment: Actually, `params` is the dynamic route params object of the page. So, in a dynamic segment defined as `[slug]`, `page.tsx`'s `params` prop will contain the following shape: `params: { slug: 'some-slug' }`.

Comment: @ivanatias correct. I meant to say params are only way to pass props. I am not sure if this is the way to handle it butnext.js has no docs yet and there is alot of issues as of now

Comment: Oh, I see. As per [Next.js docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts), it's not possible to pass data between a parent layout and its children. But what you mention in the answer is one interesting finding, didn't know you could extend `params` object and make the props available for layout's children.

Comment: Was looking for the same, but other way around, page to layout. Old _app and Component props could do this. Can't find a way to do it in v13. I guess they tried really hard to make layouts not re-render and preserve state so they removed this functionality. Then they added new fetch and much better caching so idea si that both layout and page fetch the same data which will never be fetched two times during render cycle but cached...

Comment: ... Not sure about the boilerplate, but fetch caching might be a good solution. However, what about sharing props that are not in DB and external source and cannot be fetched? Like.... each page changing one css class in header layout (i.e. color of the navigation).  Then we have to use context? And what if I want server side component and cannot use context? Tried everything but I think I'll be forced to go back to express/handlebars for my server side rendering of most pages.

Comment: You're supposed to use Context for this, which will work if the variable never changes. Otherwise I'm stuck on this in next app router too.

Comment: This indeed only works when set in the root layout. Sadly, no luck when manipulating the parameters in a client component.

Comment: Cool, but this approach should be avoided since it's not documented. And the general documented information is against this approach (and I have no idea y).

Comment: tried but couldnt get it working. any clue? https://github.com/cmgchess/can-we-pass-props-from-layout

Comment: what about if you have  navbar, for example, in your Layout and you want it to do things inside of the `{children}` how would you go about that if you are not allowed to send from Layout to page?

Comment: @matt it is not clear what you are asking..

Comment: I have asked it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78177581/how-do-i-pass-props-from-a-react-layout-template-to-children?noredirect=1#comment137824030_78177581

Answer (score 2):

To pass props from your Layout component(RootLayout for you case) to page.jsx.

`//app/blog/layout.jsx`

```
export interface items {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  params,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: {
    foo: string;
    items: items;
    age: number;

  };
}) {

  params.foo = "bar"; //string example

  params.items = { foo: "bar", bar: "foo" }; //object example

  params.age= 1; //number example

  return (
    <html lang="en" className="">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

`//app/blog/page.jsx`

```
export default function Dashboard({
  params,
}: {
  params: { foo: string; items: items; age: number };
}) {
  console.log(params.foo); //bar
  console.log(params.items); //{foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo'}
  console.log(params.age); //1
  return (
    <div></div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work

Comment: Are you able to show the code?

Comment: not anymore, but I think it didn't work because I tried to pass an object. Perhaps if I would stringify it, it would work. Maybe it's not a good idea, because it can contain a lot of data.

Comment: Hi, are you able to share some code? I tried with an object right now and its still working!

Comment: sorry I didn't get back to you, but I am not working on that project anymore.

Comment: This can only ever be used to pass strings, also you can not use this to pass components, since components are not serializable. this approach is not documented as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can just utilize React Context:

```js
// layout.tsx

import React from 'react';

export const PageContext = React.createContext(null);

export default function SomeLayout({children}) {
   const [search, setSearch] = React.useState('foo');
   return <PageContext.Provider value={search}>{children}</PageContext.Provider>
}
```

```
// page.tsx

import React from 'react';
import PageContext from '../layout.tsx';

export default function SomePage() {
   const search = React.useContext(PageContext);
   console.log(search);
   return null;
}
```

Comment: I think no other way without using context. Thanks!

Comment: so simple, yet so effective!

Comment: It's not possible to use `useContext` in any server component.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is a hack and should be avoided. You don't pass value from layout to page, instead you get the value in the page component directly.

You can optionally cache the value in the layout, using React "cache" function. See [this question about server context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66106408/retrieve-data-server-side-and-save-in-context-with-next-js), the answers explains how you can then pass a value from the page to its own children without relying on props drilling.

Comment: what about if you have  navbar, for example, in your Layout and you want it to do things inside of the `{children}` how would you go about that:?

Answer (score 0):

you can handle it like this

```
const layout = ({children}: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
const tabs = [
    {
        prefix: 'single',
        link: router.business.simcards.simcardsList,
        icon: (props) => {return( <SingleSimcardSVG {...props}/> )},
        isActive: false
    },
   
]
const childrenWithTabs = React.Children.toArray(children).map((child) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child) && typeof child.type === 'function') {
        return React.cloneElement(child, { tabs } as any);
    }
    return child;
});
return (
    <>
        {childrenWithTabs}
    </>
)}

export default layout
```

and in your child can access to props.tabs

Comment: Anyway it didn't work, it gives `undefined`

Answer (score -2):

In case if you want to send this props of children to Navbar component

```
<Navbar children = {children} />
```

Comment: No, I have a variable in root layout that I want to share with the to the {children} that was passed to the root layout. Not the navbar

Comment: Are you able to show the code where you have that variable