# How to render a server component from a client component in react 18 - nextjs 14 app router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

According to [this RFC](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/main/text/0188-server-components.md#capabilities--constraints-of-server-and-client-components):

> Client Components May **not** import Server Components or call server
> hooks/utilities, because those only work on the server.

---

I am working on a project using react 18.2 and nextjs v14 with app router.

I have this page which I am working on:

[image]

The page, is a client component, because almost everything in the page depends on client features.
This is a form, so everything depends on the React `useState()` hook.

The actual code of the page.tsx looks as follows, it's a big component, I am using a components library called **JoyUI** (by mui).

- The important part is the very first line in the code where I am using the `"use client"` directive since, as I've mentioned, this component (**NewModeratorPage**) depends on many features that are client side features.
- The second part to look at is the `<SelectCompany />` component which is in the return block of the `<NewModeratorPage />` component as shown below:

```
'use client'

import React from 'react'
import { Grid } from '@mui/material'
import useBreakpoints from '@/hooks/useBreakpoints'
import PasswordInput from '@/components/PasswordInput'
import AvatarUploader from '@/components/AvatarUploader'
import { Stack, Input, FormLabel, Checkbox } from '@mui/joy'
import {
  EmailRounded as EmailIcon,
  PhoneRounded as PhoneIcon,
  PersonRounded as PersonIcon,
} from '@mui/icons-material'
import SelectCompany from './SelectCompany'

const NewModeratorPage = () => {
  const { isDownMd } = useBreakpoints()

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={3}>
        <AvatarUploader placeholder={<PersonIcon sx={{ fontSize: 64 }} />} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
        <Stack spacing={1}>
          <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
          <Stack direction={isDownMd ? 'column' : 'row'} spacing={2}>
            <Input placeholder="First name" size="sm" fullWidth required />
            <Input placeholder="Last name" size="sm" fullWidth required />
          </Stack>
          <FormLabel>Credentials</FormLabel>
          <Stack direction={isDownMd ? 'column' : 'row'} spacing={2}>
            <Input
              placeholder="Email"
              startDecorator={<EmailIcon />}
              type="email"
              size="sm"
              fullWidth
              required
            />
            <Input placeholder="Phone number" startDecorator={<PhoneIcon />} size="sm" fullWidth />
          </Stack>
          <Stack direction={isDownMd ? 'column' : 'row'} spacing={2}>
            <PasswordInput size="sm" fullWidth required />
          </Stack>
          <Checkbox size="sm" label="Send password via email" defaultChecked />
          <SelectCompany />
        </Stack>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}

export default NewModeratorPage
```

- `<SelectCompany />` is a **server component**.
  It renders a `<Select>` with `<Options>` fetched from an API.

So, the `<SelectCompany />` involves data fetching.

Which is a good indicator that this component should be a server component.

- once the user requests the page, the page will be served with the form, and the `<SelectCompany/>` pre-fetched, with all the data.

So no loading time for fetching the companies on the client side.

- It's using the "use server" directive, to indicate that this is a server component.

Here's the code of the `<SelectCompany />` server component.

```
"use server"

import React, { PropsWithChildren } from 'react'
import { Select, Option, Avatar, Stack } from '@mui/joy'

export interface SelectCompanyProps extends PropsWithChildren {}

const SelectCompany = async ({ children, ...props }: SelectCompanyProps) => {
  const response = await fetch('/api/companies')
  const data = await response.json()
  console.log(data)

  return (
    <Select value={1}>
      <Option value={1}>
        <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
          <Avatar size="sm" />
          <React.Fragment>Company 1</React.Fragment>
        </Stack>
      </Option>
    </Select>
  )
}

export default SelectCompany
```

Firstly, I am getting this error in the browser:

```
Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server.
```

And in the terminal (I am on Linux btw), I am getting this error:

```
Internal error: Error: Server Functions cannot be called during initial render. This would create a fetch waterfall. Try to use a Server Component to pass data to Client Components instead.
```

The reason of this error, as far as I can tell, is that it's not allowed for client components to import server components,

So what is the solution to my case? I want `<SelectCompanies />` to be a server component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of supported and unsupported pattern from [nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#unsupported-pattern-importing-server-components-into-client-components)

## Unsupported

```js
'use client'
 
// You cannot import a Server Component into a Client Component.
import ServerComponent from './Server-Component'
 
export default function ClientComponent({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
 
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
 
      <ServerComponent />
    </>
  )
}
```

This is what you tried instead you can pass the server component as a child like this:

## Supported pattern

```js
'use client'
 
import { useState } from 'react'
 
export default function ClientComponent({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
 
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
      {children}
    </>
  )
}
```

```js
// This pattern works:
// You can pass a Server Component as a child or prop of a
// Client Component.
import ClientComponent from './client-component'
import ServerComponent from './server-component'
 
// Pages in Next.js are Server Components by default
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ClientComponent>
      <ServerComponent />
    </ClientComponent>
  )
}
```

By passing them as children we are aware of all server components and can render/stream them.

Comment: Thanks! the last code snippet you provided is my layout.tsx file in my case.
How can I pass props from my layout.tsx to the page.tsx?

Comment: From the docs: "Passing data between a parent layout and its children is not possible. However, you can fetch the same data in a route more than once, and React will automatically dedupe the requests without affecting performance."

Comment: Alright, I know, but now in my case I'm not fetching data, I am just passing a server component as a prop to my client component - from my layout.tsx > to my page.tsx

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't understand your question. The section supported patterns of my answer has two snippets that belong together. Your client component accepts a children prop, which you can use by nesting the elements.

Comment: My second question relates to  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74573236/pass-props-to-page-jsx-child-from-root-layout-next-js-13)

Comment: Well you can't pass data from one to another server component. Think of server components as individual functions that render and stream HTML. You would create a waterfall where one component would need to wait for its parent component. At least this is my mental model. To "solve" this issue nextjs team created a shared "cache" for data fetching. If you do not fetch data then you might not need a server component

Comment: Can you include in the answer the _shared "cache"_ approach solution, which is the recommended way by the nextjs team?

Comment: Sure https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating
Nextjs extends `fetch` to give good defaults you can force cache `fetch('https://...', { cache: 'force-cache' })` like this

Comment: So the solution is to call the endpoint in the layout.tsx, and fetch the data. Then, without passing the response as a prop to the page.tsx, I will have to duplicate the block of code which fetches the data (again) in the page.tsx file. 
right?

Comment: You can also have your Server Component just on your page. You don't need to have it in the layout at all. Layouts are just for sharing logic. So if you have multiple pages then yeah. If not just use it directly on the page