# What are the possibilities for passing props between page.tsx & layout.tsx in next 14 app router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Coming from a client-side rendered create-react-app background. I'm finding it complicated to build a proper layout.

1. Is it possible to pass props from a page component (page.tsx) to a layout component (layout.tsx)? If possible, then how?
2. Is it possible to pass props from a layout component (layout.tsx) to a page component (page.tsx)? If possible, then how?

I have made this simple layout:

[image]

The layout component includes the title, description and an optional `actions` prop, which renders whatever you pass to it at the footer of the layout:

```
// layout.tsx
export default function Layout(){
  return (
    <ResourceBox 
      title: "My Page Title", 
      description: "page description etc" 
      actions={<FormActions />}>
       {children}
    </ResourceBox>
  )
}
```

```
// page.tsx
export default function Page(){
  return (
    // some forms
  )
}
```

In my scenario, I have to somehow submit the form which is defined in my `Page` component. In order to do so, I need to have a submit button. According to the style, the button is part of the `Layout` component. Isn't it? That seems pretty logical, at least to me.

What are some options we have to work around my problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74573236/pass-props-to-page-jsx-child-from-root-layout-next-js-13/74584771#74584771

Comment: @Yilmaz, this approach should be avoided since it's not documented. And the general documented information is against this approach

Comment: you cannot pass data between layout and page. the purpose of layout is to load frame of your page faster