# Pass props in NextJS on server side (App routing)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I want share any data for each request, so I create object with these data in rootLayout

```
export interface IProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    data: any;
}

export default function RootLayout(props: IProps) {
    const {children} = props;
    props.data = {item: "hello"} // I know this is bad (only for test)
    return children;
}
```

Now I need access data in page or layout **on server side.**

```
export default function Layout(props: IProps) {
    const {children, data} = props;
    console.log("Data", data);
    return children;
}
```

Is there any way for share data per request or can I extend props for all children of root layout (on server)?

Answer (score 0):

answered **[here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#sharing-data-between-components)**:

also if you want to share data between server components base on **[**nextjs document**](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#sharing-data-between-components)** you can call your api with fetch anywhere you want:

> Instead of using React Context (which is not available on the server)
> or passing data as props, you can use fetch or React's cache function
> to fetch the same data in the components that need it, without
> worrying about making duplicate requests for the same data. This is
> because React extends fetch to automatically memoize data requests,
> and the cache function can be used when fetch is not available.

Comment: Look, I need create instance of my Class top of  the app. (root layout) and use this instance in child components (layout, page,...)

Comment: Please share your code with me so that I can guide you exactly

Comment: but if you need to send data from props, you can put it in params, and you can get it from params in any other server component.
[__this link__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74573236/pass-props-to-page-jsx-child-from-root-layout-next-js-13) will guide you

Comment: I post answer exactly with my issue. (above)

Comment: share data by props doesnt work in new NextJS, you can set params in rootLayout but in child server components it never be these data

Answer (score 0):

Okey here is exactly my issue:

RootLayout.tsx (create instance per request)

```
export interface IProps {
    children: ReactNode;
    data: {
        nodeInstance: InstancePerRequest;
    }
}

export default function RootLayout(props: IProps) {
    const {children} = props;
    props.data.nodeInstance = new InstancePerRequest();
    return children;
}
```

layout.tsx  (child server component)

```
export default function LocaleLayout(props: IProps) {
    const { children, data} = props;

    data.nodeInstance.doSomething();

    return (
        <html>
            <body className={styles.globalWrap}>{children}</body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

page.tsx

```
const Page = (props: IProps) => {
    props.data.nodeInstance.getSomething();
    return <div>Empty</div>
}

export default Page
```

All of these usages of nodeInstance has one instance per request. But this solution doesnt work.