# How do I pass props from a React Layout Template to children?

Tags: reactjs

I have layout that holds some componenents that are uniform for all pages. Lets call them `Component1` and `Component2`. I want to have an event that happens on any of the `children`, i.e., a table row is clicked, that is sent back up the layout and is sent to either one of the two components already mentioned. In my example below the child using the layout is called `Child1`

Is this possible? I have only found questions about `Next.js` and in those it is suggested that this can't/shouldn't be done. Is that the case in simple `React.js`? Or Do I have to use something like `useContext` and if so how would that be done?

**AppLayout**

```js
export default function AppLayout({
  children,
}: PropsWithChildren<Props>) {

  const [comp1, setComp1] = useState(false);
  const [comp2, setComp2] = useState(false);
  const [childVal, setChildVal] = useState(0);

  const handle = (id: number) => {
    setChildVal(id);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (childVal < 10) {  // completely contrived example
      setComp1(() => true);
    } else if (childVal < 20){
      setComp2(() => true);
    } else {
      setComp1(() => false);
      setComp2(() => false);
    }
  }, [childVal]);

  return (
      <div>
          <Compnent1 something={comp1}/>
          <main> {children} </main>    
          // I WANT TO BE ABLE TO PASS THE HANDLE FUNCTION 
          // TO THE CHILDREN AS I WOUDL WIETH OTHER COMPONENTS, 
          // i.e., tableClicked={handle}
          
          <Comoment2 something={comp2}/>
      </div>
  );
}
```

**Child1**

```js
export default function Child1({handler}) {
 
  const handleTableClicked = (id: number) => {
     handler(id);   
  }
  return (
    <AppLayout>
       <MyTable tableClicked={handleTableClicked}/>
    </AppLayout>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think you will find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children?rq=2

Comment: @matt have you tried raising the state to a common ancestor where the event handler is passed to the props of the child element?